# How to use solver in mpmath.findroot

Tags: python, mpmath

I want to find the root of a 2D nonlinear equation.
I wrote: `res = mpm.findroot(f=func1, x0=x01, tol=1.e-5, solver='MDNewton', J=JAKOB1)`
but I get this message: *ValueError: could not recognize solver*

As per the documentation of findroot, MDNewton is an acceptable solver.
Where is my mistake?

scipy.optimize.fsolve works fine, but I need the increased accuracy of mpmath.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Did u try to write it as `solver = 'mdnewton'`? I think it should be reffered in all lowercase, after researching mpmath docs.

Answer (score 1):

The `mpmath` docs gives this dictionary of keys corresponding to values of solvers.

```
{'newton':Newton, 'secant':Secant, 'mnewton':MNewton,
 'halley':Halley, 'muller':Muller, 'bisect':Bisection,
 'illinois':Illinois, 'pegasus':Pegasus, 'anderson':Anderson,
 'ridder':Ridder, 'anewton':ANewton, 'mdnewton':MDNewton}
```

As follows, writing your code as bellow shall fix the error you are experiencing.

```
res = mpm.findroot(f=func1, x0=x01, tol=1.e-5, solver='mdnewton', J=JAKOB1)
```

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was to write mdnewton, all small letters. No idea, why but it worked.